# UIImagePickerController with Photo Library with fixed size photos

Tags: objective-c, uiimagepickercontroller, fixed

i've got some code:

```
pV = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
pV.delegate = self;
pV.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;

[self presentModalViewController:pV animated:YES];
```

and i try to display only these images from Photo Library which dimension is X and Y.

any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

you need to implement your own image picker and filter the ALAssets by their properties